# How do we handle obsolete hardware recommendations?

Tags: discussion

I didn't think we'd end up with this question for a while, but it seems we have a [time traveller](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/755/parts-for-a-gaming-pc-from-2005). One of the goals of Stack Exchange is to create content that is useful to future users.

> there's a clear path from specific question to specific answer, a useful artifact on The Internet for the education of future readers. - [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125315/186281)

<sub>There are other mentions of this policy across the network, but I can't find an explicit Meta post. If someone does, please post a link in the comments below, or edit it in to this question</sub>

Eventually, we are going to have questions that are "old" and recommend "old" hardware. Using the time travel question as an example, any hardware recommended is multiple generations out of date *today*. It's asking for 10 year old hardware on a personal gaming computer. How do we handle a question that has not aged gracefully and is no longer useful because multiple generations of hardware have come out since the question was asked?

Answer (score 1):

One thing about recommendations that I've kind of noticed, even on SR, is the degree of localization that they hold. I don't want to be pointing fingers, but here's a post over at [Open Source Meta](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/202/69):

> > Do we want to allow specific questions?
>
> ## Not just 'yes', but… helllll yes!
>
> See my answer on [Is 'too specialized' a reason to close vote?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/is-too-specialized-a-reason-to-close-vote/1196#1196)

That was from Robert Cartaino, in response to a comment close reason that tried to close on the basis that we were looking for more general questions that apply to broader audiences.

---

Just because a question maybe only be relevant to a tiny group of people is not a reason to close vote, and we abolished an entire original close reason because of that. Stack Exchange thrives on questions that solve specific issues, whether or not others' may have the same problem.

Questions should have answers that are relevant to a particular situation, in a particular point in time. Let it be, as it's done it's duty of helping someone out.

#### So what should we do with the 'grandpa' questions?

Keep them, they're no more inferior or superior then any other question on the site. If someone has another recommendation question to ask, then let them ask it.

Comment: I'm not asking about specialized/too localized, but about genuinely obsolete hardware.  A lot of our questions will be fairly specific to a small group of people.